# Most performant way to do multiple updates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently do a lot of updates in SQL. We generate the statements mostly from Excel files as those will be thousands of lines SQL. The current pattern will use a new statement for each update.

```sql
update someTable set x = y where z
update someTable set x = y where z
update someTable set x = y where z
...
```

I discovered the following pattern some while ago. I am always wondering which way is more performant. As opinion based side question, what is the "cleaner" way?

```sql
declare @updates table (id, value)
insert into @updates values (a, b), (c, d), (e,f) ...

update someTable set x = @updates.value where id = @updates.id
```

Are there other even better ways I am not aware of?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: sql server, I will tag the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
update 
   sometable
set  
   x = v.value
from 
  (values (a, b), (c, d), (e, f)) v(id, value)
where 
  sometable.id = v.id;
```

I see no reason to use a table variable or temporary table.

That said, you should try performance questions on *your* database with your data.  However, I would expect the single `update` statement to be faster.  Why?  The query is only processed once and there is only a single transaction.  The three `updates` would (by default) be three different transactions and that is a lot of overhead.

Comment: It's so good. I didn't even realize how cool it was at first. It may be one of the most pretty things I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

Using `VALUES` can break down if your files are really big (hard to say exactly how big without seeing the data, you'll have to experiment).

If you are concerned with performance I would recommend also experimenting with `bcp` as well. This could be a sample pipeline (assuming you can save your excel files as csv instead):

1. `bcp` from csv file to staging table
2. Run your `UPDATE` query from staging table to prod table (use `MERGE` if you also need to do inserts or deletes)
3. `TRUNCATE` staging table (alternatively this could go at the beginning)